# How do I export a Service-Based SQL table from a Windows Form App into Excel?

Tags: vb.net

I'm building an application to simulate building a real application and not just small examples.
The application has a Main Form and 3 other Windows Forms for Orders, Sales and Products, I also have one Service-Based SQL Database which is local and application-only Database, this Service-Based DB has 3 tables, one for each Form. They are all good, it works fine and the application saves the data I place on it when I run the app from debug folder, but now I need to keep records of those tables separately in an excel sheet and I have no idea on how to do it.

I've learned everything I need to build this application from the video below and I'm enhancing it as I can, maybe if I wasn't clear enough this can help to give some context. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLs44hxV514

And this is how my application is looking like https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHZqu.jpg

Tried some examples I found online but none have worked, most of them were directed to real SQL servers, not those Service-Based ones.

I know this is not helpful at all but this is what I have so far on my Export Button.

```
    Try
        sfdProdutos.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
        sfdProdutos.Title = "Save your file."
        sfdProdutos.ShowDialog()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

And not one drop of an idea as to how to finish it, lol.
As for now I'm trying to just save it into an existing Excel file, because I know there will be something to complicate my life if I try everything at once, let that for another day.

So you can understand how I've been working with the database within the application so far, this is my 'save record' button for one of the forms

```
    If ProductTextBox.Text = Nothing Then
        ProductTextBox.Text = "unknown"
    End If
    If ProviderTextBox.Text = Nothing Then
        ProviderTextBox.Text = "unknown"
    End If
    If PriceTextBox.Text = Nothing Then
        PriceTextBox.Text = "unknown"
    End If
    If Bar_CodeTextBox.Text = Nothing Then
        Bar_CodeTextBox.Text = "unknown"
    End If
    Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.ProductsTableBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ProdutosDataSet)
        MessageBox.Show("The product has been edited.", "Information.", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        ProductTextBox.Select()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Any help is very much appreciated! 
Thanks in advance just for reading all of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a datatable and populate it from the sql table, then you can easily export that data to excel

```
Dim strSql As String = "SELECT EmpCode,EmpID,EmpName FROM dbo.Employee"
Dim dtb As New DataTable
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
      cnn.Open()
          Using dt As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, cnn)
              Dt.Fill(dtb)
          End Using
        cnn.Close()
    End Using
```

Use [this](http://www.authorcode.com/export-datatable-to-excel-in-vb-net/) to export to excel

use this to Fill (Populate) DataTable using your SqlDataAdapter

```
    Dim constring As String = "Data Source=.\SQL2005;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User id = sa;password=pass@123"
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", con)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: Yes, I've found out about that but this would make me start the application basically from scratch again, and as I don't have the knowledge yet to make a sql injection prevention system, I rather have an offline application with only a database attached to it's .exe file than a server.

Should have a way to work with this Service-Based Db, right? Otherwise, what's the point of it?